# Update app namespace Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I finally decided to upgrade my Laravel app from 5.1 to 5.2, so I followed the upgrade guide. I started learning Laravel right at 5.1 so this is my first upgrade, I upgraded because I am looking forward to the api guard driver, however, I noticed that the web and api middlewares are not there, since those are under my App namespace.

My question might be dumb, but I didn't find anything on the upgrade guide, so.. basically I have to manually update all my App folder (Middlewares, Providers, etc) to match L5.2 right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I've done the same thing. We need to go manually and update the namespace and other relevant things. Find And replace will work. It will not take more time.

Comment: 10-4.. will do. I just wanted a second opinion on that.

Comment: Yes Right. I've also re-searched on that. But in upgrade guide they have mentioned that you need to manually and update it.